# Mark first sentence in a document

Tags: uima, ruta

I already have marked Sentences in a document (type: Sentence). How can I mark the first one as the document title? I already tried `Sentence{->MARKFIRST(DocTitle)};`, but this didn't work.

All the best
Philipp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that`s easy:

# Sentence{-> DocTitle};

"#" consumes everything until the first Sentence annotation.
All the best